# How would I go about overriding a task provided by another plugin in a standalone project? Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am working on creating a Gradle plugin via a standalone project. For one of my plugin's tasks, I would like to override or add onto a task provided by the `java` plugin (processResources). Is there a way to do this in a standalone project? I've seen it be overridden directly in the `build.gradle` file but is there any way to override it in a task class?

For example, task class:

```
class Process extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    void process() {
        project.processResources {
           // I tried overriding this way with no prevail.
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the overridden version to run each time my `:boot` or `:bootWar` task is run (which is provided by the `spring` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To override/customize the provided `processResources` contributed by the `java` plugin, you must first:

1. Locate/Retrieve the task
2. Configure task

What you're trying to do at the moment is create a task that customizes a task, which doesn't make sense. Tasks don't customize other tasks, they perform actionable actions such as executing tests.

Here's an example plugin that does the above steps in Java:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin;
import org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources;

public class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().named(JavaPlugin.PROCESS_RESOURCES_TASK_NAME, ProcessResources.class, (processResources) -> {
            processResources.from("....."); // configure the task in the lambda
        });
    }
}
```